# ASP.Net User Control Event Bubbling (C#)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, event-bubbling

Many thanks in advance.  I've done my due diligence and researched for 2 days, but can't seem to wrap my mind around what online tutorials describe.

The situation: Lead Programmer ups and quits.  Owner of firm knows I've done some (novice) VB.NET on the side and asks me to wire up functionality between 2 custom user controls on his intranet app (written in C#.  Small consideration for answering pros -- I'm fluent in Visual Studio...but still learning C#).

Here's a simplified description of controls, but hopefully enough to get us going in the right direction:

UserControl_1 contains multiple linkbuttons that, when clicked, should change the value of the SelectParameter being used by an ObjectDataSource in UserControl_2:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="OpenBtn1" runat="server" Text="Show Open Requests" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="ClosedBtn1" runat="server" Text="Show Closed Requests" />
```

UserControl_2 (GridView with DataSource):

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
    SelectMethod="GetDataBy_Status" 
    TypeName="adhoc_TblAdptrs.adhoc_TblAdptr">
    <SelectParameters>
       <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="All" Name="status" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:GridView1 ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" />
```

What I'd like to do pass a new default value to the SelectParameter of the the ObjectDataSource in UserControl_2.  I'm looking forward to a personalized explanation from the pros!  Your help is greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't knock carpentry.  It's a useful skill, and you can make money at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expose a property in UserControl2 that will, in turn, set the parameter value

```
public string ParamValue { get; set; }

protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) {
    if (ParamValue.Length > 0){
        e.InputParameters["status"] = ParamValue;
    }
}
```

Also, in the page create public method that will set the property in the control

```
public void SetParamValue(string Value){
    UserControl_2.ParamValue = Value;
}
```

From here, in the linkbutton click event, you can just set the public property using the page's method:

```
  void OpenBtn1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){
     ((YourPageClassHere)this.Page).SetParamValue("Open");
  }
```

***This method will get the job done but it will couple the control with the linkbuttons to this specific page.***

If you want to remove the coupling then you could implement an Interface with the method

```
public interface IParameterValuePage{
    public void SetParamValue(string Value)
}
```

Then in your page you would implement it and do a check in the code for the control page

```
  void OpenBtn1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){
      if (this.Page is IParameterValuePage){
          ((IParameterValuePage)this.Page).SetParamValue("Open");
      }
      else{
          throw new Exception("Page must implement IParameterValuePage");
      }
  }
```

Comment: +1. I agree with this answer. Plus one other consideration.. I wonder if both user controls could be combined into one? They seem tightly coupled already...

Comment: I thought the same thing until I found that same control used in different places throughout his site where it wouldn't make sense to have the linkbuttons tied in.

Comment: Russ -- I understand what you suggested thus far, but...don't I need a way to "bubble" the click event of the linkbutton in UserControl_1 up to the page, so that a function on the page can alter the parameter? (I ask that because if UserControl_1 is used in a page where the gridview/ObjectDataSource in UserControl_2 doesn't exists, wouldn't that throw an error?)

Comment: @Daniel, please see my edits, as I have changed a few things and added a better solution that wouldn't require coupling.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks, Russ.  You've given me very clear instruction.  Very, very much appreciated!